# when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Got: "'MY _PUBLIC _KEY'"

Tags: web3.py, python, django

web3s.py

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

url = 'https://kovan.infura.io/v3/NODE'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))

abi = json.loads('[{"ABI"}]')
Raw_ADDRESS = MY_ADDRESS 
address = web3.toChecksumAddress(Raw_ADDRESS) 
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address,abi=ABI)
default_GasPrice = '5'

def firstMethod(Address1,publicKey,privateKey,GasPrice = default_GasPrice ) :

    Address1 = web3.toChecksumAddress(Address1) 
    publicKey = web3.toChecksumAddress(publicKey) 

    if web3.isConnected()  :    
        nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(publicKey) 
        transaction = contract.functions.firstMethod(Address1).buildTransaction({
            'from': publicKey , 
            'gasPrice': web3.toWei(GasPrice, 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce ,
            })
...
```

when i define address1 and address2 in web3s.py , codes work well
but when i call firstMethod() in another file (from Django-Rest View) after import and pass **same** arguments , it returns :

```
File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_utils/conversions.py", line 159, in hexstr_if_str
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Got: "'0x6e...24'"
```

i use infura not etherscan

what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if it solves your problem, But may give you an idea at least.

1. The value of `"'0x6e...24'"` is double stringified. Which means there are multiple quotations around your hex string. One of them is excessive, you can remove it or you can avoid it to happen in the first place. It's probably a problem with your view/ui components.
2. Try to convert your string to a hex string data type. Keep in mind to pass your address without `0x`. Then use converted value in the rest of the steps.

   hex_string = bytes.fromhex('2d693f8e73d3a395ff7bb70ee278b5fed9b86564')