when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Error in Web3.toChecksumAddress function
I get an error when I try to run the following code
cc = "0x483a49dcf80B932cf94734B8fd5d3p9aa508a933"
ToAdd = Web3.toChecksumAddress(cc)

The error I get.
when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Got: '0x483a49dcf80B932cf94734B8fd5d3p9aa508a933'

Duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100028/when-sending-a-str-it-must-be-a-hex-string-got-my-public-key?rq=1

After a thorough investigation, I realized that the cause of this error is the wrong address. I realized that if you change one letter of the address, this error may occur, but if you change the letter to uppercase or lowercase, this function detects and corrects it. For example, if you change the letter "U" to "u", it does not give an error, but corrects it
